# send a URL to background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm getting an URL via content script and try to pass it to my background page via sendMessage but I receive `[object Object]`.

content script:

```
var kom = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='permalink']");
var linkX = kom[0];

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {
      link: linkX
    });
```

background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log("MY LINK: " + response.link);
});
```

I found that you can't pass DOM nodes with messaging and data must be JSON-serializable.

How can I send my URL?

Comment: @mike `JSON.stringify()` will likely not work on an HTML Element because it has circular references.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan you are right.  I didn't see that he had defined `kom` on line 1, for some reason I thought he was receiving the object and passing it on again.  I'll withdraw my comment.  Knowing what the object is definitely lets us know how we should pass along the data.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
{
    link: linkX.href
});
```

Comment: Not sure why they'd want the `src` attribute of an anchor...

Comment: thx for the answer,.src didnt work but .href

Comment: I'm getting kind of rusty

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ..

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
     link: linkX.href
});
```

Comment: thx very much that worked :)

Comment: you are welcome @bimbam can you give correct mark to answer to help others reach answer ^_^

Comment: i did that and it was registered but ive not enough reputation :)

Comment: one additional quastion plz, now i have the same prob with var theName = document.querySelector("h2"); any suggestions? thx jana

Comment: never mind, can you send more details about the prob ?

Comment: like the link before i tried to send i get the same [object Object] message when i try to send the result of document.querySelector("h2")... but that's not a link, just text

Comment: You can try `var theName = document.querySelector("h2").innerText;` to get the inner text

Comment: thy again, innerText works, but i think the main problem is the iframe in which the content script is running http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868426/content-script-and-iframe ...really makes me mad

Comment: Can you give me the HTML code which you want to select by `div.posting.upost.upost-is-expanded[data-is-selected*='true']` to hep me test and provide you with answer ? @bimbam

Comment: sry for the delay ahmed.. i can send u a link http://derstandard.at/2000054634819/Dr-Oetker-bringt-Schoko-Pizza-auch-inOesterreich-auf-den-Markt#posting-1019413480    result should be 'bimbam007' in this case. as i wrote in my other topic: this selector works for me in an content script for the active tab, but it doesnt work when the content script runs in the iframe in background page. thx! jana